# Any good LVM tutorial?

Tags: lvm, documentation

I'm planning to user LVM in my next Linux installation, any links to good LVM tutorials/guides/FAQs would be welcomed.

Comment: I think there is a good deal of subjectivity over what makes a "good" tutorial; you might consider making this a "community wiki" question.  (For instance, I disagree with Gilles' opinion -stated below- that differences between LVM1 and LVM2 are significant at a tutorial level.)

Comment: @Riccardo: I've forgotten the specifics (I think root on LVM was part of it), but I remember quite a bit of headscratching when I started with LVM (2004 IIRC), because of differences between LVM1 (which pretty much all then available material was about) and LVM2 (which I had). I don't expect this to be relevant now though, I think most available material is about LVM2 only.

Comment: @Gilles: I had no intent to argue about it; it just came handy as an example of how "good tutorial" may mean different things to different people... :-)

Comment: above explains all but still *you can ask here* ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the [LVM HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) to be very clear.

It has probably more info than you want from a first-time tutorial, but reading sections 1. to 3. and 11. to 13. should give you a comprehensive introduction to LVM concepts and its usage in live systems; these days, most Linux distribution have good LVM support out-of-the-box, so you can safely skip the "Installation" and "Scripts" parts.

Comment: +1 for the TLDP links: I found that the LVM document to be clear and simple too.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion one of the best resources for LVM was [Red Hats LVM Administrators Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/pdf/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-5-Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration-en-US.pdf), check it out.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm

http://www.linuxconfig.org/Linux_lvm_-_Logical_Volume_Manager

These are literally the first few links I get from searching for "LVM tutorial", this stuff isn't exactly hard to find. ;)

Comment: For a question like this, posting the results of a google search is not useful. You've cited some LVM tutorials, but are they *good* LVM tutorials? (When I learnt LVM a few years, there were *no* good LVM tutorials, and even no good reference documentation: they all covered LVM1, but I had LVM2 and many things were different.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated more. When I was learning LVM about six months ago, these are tutorials that I found helpful. The fact that they show up first in the search results was mostly luck

Comment: I found  the howto forge one very clear and concise, without any clutter whatsoever, got up to speed on using LVM in no time

Answer (score 1):

Cover only basic things, but I like author's style. IMHO nice start for begginers:

http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-Guide-EN-LVM2